# Struggling to type a TypeScript function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got this TypeScript error and I don't fully understand what's going on:

```
src/helpers.ts:11:14 - error TS2322: Type '<T extends "horizontal" | "vertical" | undefined, U extends AriaRole | undefined>(ariaOrientation: T, role: U) => "horizontal" | "vertical" | NonNullable<T> | "both"' is not assignable to type 'ResolveOrientationFunction'.
  Type '"horizontal" | "vertical" | NonNullable<T> | "both"' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<T> | "both"'.
    Type '"horizontal"' is not assignable to type 'NonNullable<T> | "both"'.
```

Here is my function:

```js
import { type HTMLAttributes } from "react";

type ResolveOrientationFunction = <
  T extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["aria-orientation"],
  U extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["role"]
>(
  ariaOrientation: T,
  role: U
) => "both" | NonNullable<T>;

export const resolveOrientation: ResolveOrientationFunction = (ariaOrientation, role) => {
  if (ariaOrientation === undefined) {
    switch (role) {
      case "menubar":
      case "slider":
      case "tablist":
      case "toolbar": {
        return "horizontal";
      }

      case "listbox":
      case "menu":
      case "scrollbar":
      case "tree": {
        return "vertical";
      }
    }
  }

  return ariaOrientation ?? "both";
};
```

The function is supposed to return `"both" | "horizontal" | "vertical"`.

`HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["aria-orientation"]` is actually `"horizontal" | "vertical" | undefined` and `HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["role"]` is `React.AriaRole | undefined`.

I'm actually trying to make this function match the type `"both" | NonNullable<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["aria-orientation"]>`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're trying to make this generic? If you make it a regular function with specific types [like this](https://tsplay.dev/NBQZxw) it compiles cleanly; does that meet your needs or is there something missing?

Comment: No particular reason, I guess I was too blind to see the obvious... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ResolveOrientationFunction` type definition,

```
type ResolveOrientationFunction = <
  T extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["aria-orientation"],
  U extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["role"]
>(
  ariaOrientation: T,
  role: U
) => "both" | NonNullable<T>;
```

is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in both `T`, the type of `ariaOrientation`, and `U`, the type of `role`.  It returns a value of type `"both" | NonNullable<T>`.  So if `T` is `undefined` because `ariaOrientation` is `undefined`, then the function must return `"both" | NonNullable<undefined>` which is `"both"`.  But your implementation doesn't do that.  It can instead return `"horizontal"` or `"vertical"` depending on `role`.

So your `resolveOrientation` function is not a valid `ResolveOrientation`.

---

It's not clear that you need the function to be generic at all.  Certainly the `U` type parameter isn't useful as written, since it has no effect on the return type.  And you don't really want the `T` type parameter to be reflected directly in the output type either.  It seems like your return type should just be `"both" | "vertical" | "horizontal"` without reference to `T` or `U`.  And if you have a generic function where there's no obvious dependency on the type parameters, then you might not want a generic function in the first place.

If you change the generics to specific types like this:

```
type AriaOrientation = HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["aria-orientation"];
type AriaRole = HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["role"]
type ResolveOrientationFunction =
    (ariaOrientation: AriaOrientation, role: AriaRole) => 
    "both" | NonNullable<AriaOrientation>;
```

Then your function compiles cleanly:

```
export const resolveOrientation: ResolveOrientationFunction = (ariaOrientation, role) => {
    if (ariaOrientation === undefined) {
        switch (role) {
            case "menubar":
            case "slider":
            case "tablist":
            case "toolbar": {
                return "horizontal";
            }

            case "listbox":
            case "menu":
            case "scrollbar":
            case "tree": {
                return "vertical";
            }
        }
    }

    return ariaOrientation ?? "both";
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzjAnmApnAEgFQLIAyAgjDFMAEYCuM6AznAL5wBmUEIcARFOgIYBjGFwDcAKFQY4RcnwDy5dADsYfGMAhK4AXmz5ipctVp0APLkIBRADboQymAD4A2lz6yAtNGAO1GpVwAuuKSmDLAfABKELY6eoQkZJQ09Ob6NnYOLjwx6EESaJiR9DEAbugKPip+mgBiVEpC-jpicG1wABTuEZW+6poAXNKyvdX9SgA0cOy2Q+FRuQCUOo7cFBAwABZccAA+cABymgdU1tZ8FLam86Oq447iYugAHpCwcAKadPC8dGUVijG-iGxT+1nKtxqSnqjXGcS6I0Bd38Uxm6GW2lWCFa7WALE63XkSKhOm0ugaABN0CxgEp0BTltj2sy4HQAO7AGACTadNGMnEslkCPh0TBcexKKgUdxcAYCwXtYWi7h0azAKlQWXyhUfEVi1SXYDfLU65lK-UQGLSzVDJmmwW8GBUKBaLibbwAL00qmsom1CsYYn9gvN3DV33WzxN9t1yvFyio0ftoa4dAEM2s1qTppTZHQeVtwdNjudrvKsGAwt94hjTCLgeZgflJZdcEJkLhAH5O2sNttxIxHkA)

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation, this is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with [jcalz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) comment, the intent to make this function generic might not be what you to achieve eventually. But I will try to explain *why* this snippet is giving an error.

If you notice the return type `NonNullable<T>`, it actually means a value that is of the type `T`. Now, `T` can be anything as long as it extends `HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["aria-orientation"]`. In the function however, we're returning either only a `horizontal` or a `vertical` or a `both` but as per the return type it needs to be of type `T`

Which can be more than just `vertical`, `horizontal` or `both`.

We can fix this by using non generic return type (which is what we're actually returning as well). When we replace `NonNullable<T>` with `HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["aria-orientation"]` it works.

Here's your example with a non generic return type.

```
import { type HTMLAttributes } from "react";

type ResolveOrientationFunction = <
  T extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["aria-orientation"],
  U extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["role"]
>(
  ariaOrientation: T,
  role: U
) => "both" | HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>["aria-orientation"];

export const resolveOrientation: ResolveOrientationFunction = (ariaOrientation, role) => {
  if (ariaOrientation === undefined) {
    switch (role) {
      case "menubar":
      case "slider":
      case "tablist":
      case "toolbar": {
        return "horizontal";
      }

      case "listbox":
      case "menu":
      case "scrollbar":
      case "tree": {
        return "vertical";
      }
    }
  }

  return ariaOrientation ?? "both";
};
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It did help, thank you! Had to accept @jcalz answer but this was definitely helpful.